# Print list of items line by line in a file

Tags: python

Is it possible to Print the below Result line by line?

I tried to add \n on `print(final \n, file=f)`. But that's not working.

Here is the Code:

```
def calcperm(arr, size):
    result = set([()])
    for dummy_idx in range(size):
        temp = set()
        for dummy_lst in result:
            for dummy_outcome in arr:
                if dummy_outcome not in dummy_lst:
                    new_seq = list(dummy_lst)
                    new_seq.append(dummy_outcome)
                    temp.add(tuple(new_seq))
        result = temp
    return result

lst = [1, 2, 3, 4]
seq = 3
final = calcperm(lst, seq)
print(len(final))
with open('file.txt', 'w') as f:
    print(final, file=f)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! The question title and body don't seem to match, and I don't understand your question. Please [edit] to clarify. See [ask] for reference. **Edit**: I just saw Rory's answer, and I get what you're asking now, but I still think the title doesn't match the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your last two lines (the `with` structure) with this:

```
with open('file.txt', 'w') as f:
    for item in final:
        print(item, file=f)
```

This will print all 24 tuples in `final` to your file, line by line.

Comment: Thanks so much! I found out line needs to be item.

Comment: @Alitai: Yes, you are right. I had an error, now corrected.